# Web video gallery

Tags: plugins, video, gallery, web

I'm looking for a simple plugin to integrate a video gallery in a website. I prefer it to be based on flash rather than HTML5 (for browser compatibility) and it should play videos hosted localy.

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You could consider open-source solutions like: 1.JWPlayer: [www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)(maybe the most used)

2.FlowPlayer: http://flowplayer.org/
3.FLV Player: http://flv-player.net/